Memory Manager C
I have a test file and when i test my memory manager file, when the test is ran it should allocate 512 bytes once, and then 512 twice and at last when trying to allocate 100 bytes it should not go through because we have initialized exactly 1024 bytes in total. My problem is that my allocation function only goes through and allocates the first 512 bytes and after it doesn't allocate anymore.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Memory_Block {
    size_t size;
    int free;  // 1 if free, 0 if used
    struct Memory_Block* next;
} Memory_Block;

void* memory_pool = NULL;
Memory_Block* free_memory_array = NULL;
size_t memory_left = 0;

void mem_init(size_t size) {
    memory_pool = malloc(size);
    if (memory_pool == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory pool\n");
        return;
    }

    free_memory_array = (Memory_Block*) memory_pool;
    free_memory_array->size = size - sizeof(Memory_Block); 
    free_memory_array->free = 1;
    free_memory_array->next = NULL;
    
    memory_left = free_memory_array->size;
}

void* mem_alloc(size_t size) {
    Memory_Block* current = free_memory_array;

    if (size == 0 || memory_left < size + sizeof(Memory_Block)) {
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->free && current->size >= size) {

            if (current->size > size + sizeof(Memory_Block)) { 
                Memory_Block* new_block = (Memory_Block*) ((char*)current + sizeof(Memory_Block) + size);
                new_block->size = current->size - size - sizeof(Memory_Block);
                new_block->free = 1;
                new_block->next = current->next;

                current->size = size;
                current->next = new_block;
            }

            current->free = 0;
            memory_left -= size + sizeof(Memory_Block); 
            printf("%zu Memory left\n", memory_left);
            return (void*)(current + 1);  
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("Not enough memory\n");
    return NULL;
}

void mem_free(void* block) {
    if (block == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Memory_Block* mem_block = (Memory_Block*)block - 1;
    mem_block->free = 1;
    memory_left += mem_block->size + sizeof(Memory_Block);

    Memory_Block* current = free_memory_array;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->free && current->next && current->next->free) {
            current->size += sizeof(Memory_Block) + current->next->size;
            current->next = current->next->next;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void* mem_resize(void* block, size_t new_size) {
    if (block == NULL) {
        return mem_alloc(new_size);
    }

    Memory_Block* mem_block = (Memory_Block*)block - 1;

    if (mem_block->size >= new_size) {
        return block;
    }

    void* new_block = mem_alloc(new_size);
    if (new_block != NULL) {
        memcpy(new_block, block, mem_block->size);
        mem_free(block);
    }

    return new_block;
}

void mem_deinit() {
    free(memory_pool);
    memory_pool = NULL;
    free_memory_array = NULL;
    memory_left = 0;
}

int main() {
    mem_init(1024);  // Initialize with 1KB of memory
    void *block1 = mem_alloc(512);
    printf("Block1 allocated: %p\n", block1);
    
    void *block2 = mem_alloc(512);
    printf("Block2 allocated: %p\n", block2);
    
    void *block3 = mem_alloc(100);  // This should fail, no space left
    printf("Block3 allocated: %p (should be NULL)\n", block3);
    
    mem_free(block1);
    mem_free(block2);
    mem_deinit();

    return 0;
}

I tried to include the bytes that are needed for the memory block structure (code below) but the problem is that then it will become more than 512 bytes for each allocation.

What Andreas Wenzel said above. Also, define what you mean by "it doesn't allocate anymore."  In engineering, it is of paramount importance to always be unambiguous.

Perhaps not OP's issue with 512 byte allocations yet (Memory_Block*) ((char*)current + sizeof(Memory_Block) + size) is problem when the computed address is not aligned for a Memory_Block.

I mean that the first allocation takes more than 512 bytes, which it shouldn't so memory left is less than 512 so it runs into the "memory_left < size" and prints out "Not enough memory".

I don't understand your algorithm. Why do you allocate a new block when a free block is large enough for the request? That seems backwards.

Because when splitting i will have a block with the exact bytes requested, the other block will be free for other allocations.

Can you share the output please?
